# Trivially solving for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having a bit of a brain-fart.

I want to rearrange this for $b$

$$a = b - c b$$

So...

$$
\begin{align}
a & = b - c b \\
a & = b ( 1 - c ) \\
\frac{a}{(1-c)} & = b \\
b & = \frac{a}{1-c}
\end{align}
$$

I wanted to be certain, so I used WolframAlpha with this input:

```
solve a = b-cb for b
```

...which gives me this output:

$$b = -\frac{a}{c-1}$$

Unless I'm mistaken (which I probably am) the two definitions of $b$ are not equivalent, I'm assuming Alpha is right, so where did I go wrong?

Comment: Don't you know that $1-c=-(c-1)$?

Comment: You are almost there. Note that $$b=\frac{a}{1-c}=\frac{a}{-(c-1)}=-\frac{a}{c-1}.$$

Comment: The answers are equivalent; yours is more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: @quasi That's why I assumed I was wrong because Alpha's answer "has more stuff".

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan The $1-c=-(c-1)$ equivalence is not intuitive to me.

Comment: You don't need to assume that your answer is wrong, because the truth is your answer is correct.

Comment: How come you're not convinced that $1-c=-(c-1)$? You want us to prove it?

Comment: Machines generally don't have the artistic sense that we humans have.

Comment: @Dai: The minus in front of a parenthesized expression can be re-expressed as a multiplication by $-1$. Then just apply the distributive law.

Comment: @Dai $-(c-1) = (-1) \cdot (c-1) = (-1) \cdot c - (-1) \cdot 1 = -c + 1 = 1 - c\,$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is absolutely correct. As mentioned in the comments, your answer is the more aesthetically pleasing one, since it includes fewer minuses. To show equivalence, note the following:

$$\frac{-a}{b} = -\frac{a}{b} = \frac{a}{-b}$$

With this in mind, we can show that $$-\frac{a}{c-1} = \frac{a}{-(c-1)} = \frac{a}{-c+1}=\frac{a}{1-c}$$

If you want to test this further, plug in any random *a* and *b*, and show that the two statements are equal. Hope this helps!